# MYSQL - ON DUPLICATE KEY does not update

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update, insert-into, on-duplicate-key

I having been having the worst luck with updating and inserting into a database. My insert into a database works perfectly, i just cannot update.

I have tired two seperate queries one for update the other insert, but updating never works. I am now using the ON DUPLICATE KEY trigger and once again the information just adds a record each time instead of updating. Where am i going wrong? I have been working on this for a day and half now and can't seem to get anywhere. newbee problems!

```
  <?php
   $Cust_ID = $_SESSION["CustomerID"];
   if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
      $c_fname = $_POST['fname'];
      $c_lname = $_POST['lname'];
      $c_email = $_POST['email'];
      $c_phone = $_POST['phone'];

  // Save $_POST to $_SESSION
  //query

   $insert_det = "INSERT INTO  Cus_acc_details(CUS_Fname,CUS_Lname,Cus_Email,CUS_Phone) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE
    CUS_Fname = '$c_fname',
    Cus_Lname = '$c_lname'";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_det);
//new
// $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c);
//debugging
//$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $insert_c)  or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssi', $c_fname, $c_lname, $c_email, $c_phone);

/* execute query */
$r = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

// if inserted echo the following messges
if ($r) {
    echo "<script> alert('registration sucessful')</script>";
}
} else {
echo "<b>Oops! Your passwords do not </b>";
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<section class="container">
    <form id="myform " class="Form" method="post" action="Cus_Account.php?c_id=<?php echo $c_id ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">

        <!--                    <div id="first">-->
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['fname']; ?>" required> 
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['lname']; ?>"  required>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['Cus_Email']; ?>" required>
        <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['phone']; ?>"  required>
        <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
        <br>
    </form>
```

both the Customer_id and Cus-_email field's are set as unique on the bd, however, records keep inserting into the db. any help would be appreciated.

SHOW CREATE

```
CREATE TABLE `Cus_acc_details` (
`CustomerID` tinyint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`AcctId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`CUS_Fname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`Cus_Lname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`CUS_Phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`Cus_Email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
UNIQUE KEY `CustomerID` (`CustomerID`),
UNIQUE KEY `CustomerID_2` (`CustomerID`,`Cus_Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=outfit
```

Comment: Can you add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE Cus_acc_details` output to the question?

Comment: Is the unique index on `cus_email` by itself, or is it a composite index like `(customer_id, cus_email)`? The latter doesn't make `cus_email` unique, only the combination of ID and email. And since each inserted row gets a different ID, the duplicate key condition doesn't happen.

Comment: @Barmar how do i get around this. As the fname, lname cannot be unique

Comment: @Barmar CREATE TABLE `Cus_acc_details` (
 `CustomerID` tinyint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `AcctId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `CUS_Fname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Cus_Lname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CUS_Phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `Cus_Email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `CustomerID` (`CustomerID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `CustomerID_2` (`CustomerID`,`Cus_Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment, so it can be formatted readably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
UNIQUE KEY CustomerID_2 (CustomerID, Cus_Email)
```

to:

```
UNIQUE KEY Email (Cus_Email)
```

Otherwise, it only makes the combination of customer ID and email unique, not the email by itself, so you can have duplicate emails with different IDs. Since your `INSERT` doesn't specify the ID (because it's added automatically with `AUTO_INCREMENT`), the inserted data doesn't have a duplicate key.

ALso, you don't need

```
UNIQUE KEY CustomerID (CustomerID)
```

because the primary key is automatically a unique key.

So do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Cus_acc_details 
    DROP KEY CustomerID, 
    DROP KEY CustomerID_2, 
    ADD UNIQUE KEY Email (Cus_Email);
```

Comment: Thank you. so much. I cannot believe i was so close but so far